# Angular cli installation issues

Tags: angular-cli

can someone suggest a solution to this problem? I am getting following error when I try to create a component in angular using **ng g c** command. You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the generate command.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the current directory you are in when running CLI commands (like `ng g c`) is the root directory, or a subdirectory of, the application you generated using the Angular CLI.

So, if you created an Angular application using `ng new my-app`, then make sure to `cd` into the folder `ng new` created (my-app in this case) before running any CLI (`ng g ..`) code generation commands.

Running `ng` code generation commands outside of a directory where the CLI installed will produce the error you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The command is executed in root dir of  the angular cli project. Is there any other way to check angular - cli is installed ?

Comment: You can try running `ng -v` to see if the locally installed version is correct in the directory you are working in. Keep in mind too that you have to install the CLI both globally (`npm install -g @angular/cli`), and locally `npm install @angular/cli` (without the -g), in order for it to work. Using `ng new` should do the install locally for you.